# WPF : Define binding's default

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, templates, default

In WPF, I would like to be able to template how my bindings are applied by default.

For instance, I want to write :

```
Text="{Binding Path=PedigreeName}"
```

But it would be as if I had typed :

```
Text="{Binding Path=PedigreeName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

- Patrick

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to Joe White's good answer, you could also create a class that inherits from Binding and sets the default property values you need. For instance :

```
public class TwoWayBinding : Binding
{
    public TwoWayBinding()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public TwoWayBinding(string path)
      : base(path)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up implementing it that way.
[code]
 public class ValidationBinding : Binding
  {
    public ValidationBinding()
    {
      Initialize();
    }

    public ValidationBinding(string path)
      : base(path)
    {
      Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
      Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
      UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
      NotifyOnValidationError = true;
      ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
      ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
    }
  }
[/code]

Comment: @vines: `Text="{my:TwoWayBinding Path=PedigreeName}"`

Answer (score 27):

Use one of the overloads of [DependencyProperty.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.register.aspx) that take a PropertyMetadata. Pass an instance of [FrameworkPropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata_properties.aspx) and set its properties.

```
public class Dog {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PedigreeNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PedigreeName", typeof(string), typeof(Dog),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus
            }
        );
```

I don't offhand see a way to set the defaults for NotifyOnValidationError, ValidatesOnDataErrors, or ValidatesOnExceptions, but I haven't used this enough to be sure what to look for; they may be there.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea, but in my case, the Dog class is in a business model project.  I don't want to add a dependency on System.Windows for this project.  The solution I was looking fo was in that direction, something like putting
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Binding}">
            <Setter Property="Mode" Value="TwoWay" />
                  ...
            <Setter Property="ValidatesOnDataErrors" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ValidatesOnExceptions" Value="True" />
        </Style>

In the App.xaml, but have not found anything matching...  Thanks again !