# Default settings for bound WPF DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I've created a custom user control named `MyCustomComboBox`. Everywhere in the application I put it I do the following:

```
    <Widgets:MyCustomComboBox
        Foo="{Binding Foo, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

MyCustomComboxBox has the dependency property `Foo`, I have some validation and other logic in the combobox which is the very reason why I wrapped it up in a custom control.

The custom combobox is included another user control which also has a `Foo` property, which the combobox's is bound to.

But I also have to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `Mode`, I would like to somehow specify that those are the default values when binding to that DependencyProperty. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `BindingMode` can be specified in the dependency property metadata:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Foo",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MyCustomComboBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        null,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault);
```

However, to my knowledge there is no way to provide a default for the update source trigger.

Comment: There is a way to set the default update source trigger as well; just found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094509/wpf-define-bindings-default/1094744#1094744) which is essentially a duplicate of my question. Much nice extra information there.